# It's possible to create method inside the method?

Tags: c#

How can I create a method inside the method without using NestedClass?

For example I want to call a method like the ff:

```
Method1("sample string").Method2(12345).ToString();
```

And the method I was thinking is:

```
public string Method1(string text)
{
   string Method2(int num1)
   {
      return text + num1;
   }
   return Method2;
}
```

Or

```
public string Method1(string text).Method2(int num1)
{
    Return text + num1;
}
```

Something like that exist? if so what kind of method is that?

Comment: You cannot nest named methods. However, you can nest anonymous methods as deep you like, however inadvisable as that might be. See the C# docs on MSDN for anonymous methods.

Comment: Are you trying to get partial method/function application in C#? What you're trying to achieve (`Method1("sample string").Method2(12345).ToString();` syntax) is definitely possible, but it's not as easy as you'd want it to be.

Comment: That has got to be the weirdest C# pseudo syntax I have ever seen. There *has* to be a better way to get what you are going for (whatever that is).

Comment: @BradleyDotNET It's weird because it's just a sample what I want to do and what I've tried to do.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Even it's hard can you give me a link for that kind of method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return either a [`Func`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (a method with a return value) or an [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (no return value)

```
public Func<int> Example()
{
    return () => 10
}

public Action<int> ExmapleAction()
{
    (i) => Console.WriteLine(i) // doesn't return, but acts on passed value
}
```

In your case you could do the following:

```
public Func<string, object> Method1(string value) { return (s) => new object(); }
```

And call it like this:

```
Method1("value")("otherValue");
```

If you are set on chaining the methods the only way that doesn't need to create a specific type would the extension method one (Steve's answer)

Comment: How does it help to get `public string Method1(string text).Method2(int num)` or `Method1("sample string").Method2(12345).ToString();` working?

Comment: It helps because the parent method can return a child method that can be called with user parameters. Instead of Method1("bla").Method2("bli") where Method1 just would have to return an object, you would use method1("bla")("bli")

Comment: Of course if you want to return instances with member methods it is still possible but then I don't see how you could avoid nested classes as OP mentions, or at least classes in a hierarchy. If you do, I'd be most interested in seeing how, @MarcinJuraszek

Answer (score 2):

You can't do nested methods in c#. But an extension method would be able to do what you want.

```
//xxclass
public string Method1(string text)
{
   return text;
}

public static class stringExtension
{
    public static string Method2(this string s, int num1)
    {
       return s + num1;
    }
}


Method1("sample string").Method2(12345).ToString();
```

Comment: Interesting, but how can I declare the `Method1("sample string ").Method2(12345).ToString()`?

Comment: @LeoSarmiento you declare method1 in your class, and then make a extension class(stringExtension) somewhere (doesn't have to be the same file) and then include the namespace whenever you want to call it.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with @Steve. In general, they don't even have to be `string`s, as long as `Method1` returns a value/instance that has `Method2` defined (either as an actual member of that class/struct or an extension method as in @Steve's example...)

Answer (score 1):

```
public string Method1(string text)
{
    Func<string,string,string> method = (val1,val2) => {return val1 + val2}; 

    return method("hello", "world");
}
```

Use delegates if you need local functions. You can also use Action if you need a void method since Func must return a value.

Comment: How the function know that val1 and val2 is a string? I think it will only give me an error.

Comment: I updated. You are right. The last parameter is the return type and the other two are the types of the input parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for a [Fluent Interface](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1187/creating-a-c-fluent-api).